# C# BsonDocument remove elements with no value

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net webapi, C#, and Mongo.

I have a C# Poco class like this

```
public class item {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Value {get;set;}
  public string Note {get;set;}
}
```

Before a document is saved I started to convert it to a BsonDocment so that a property can be injected (only for internal use of the api), before going to the client it is stripped out when it is deserialized.

Here is the code that converts it and adds the new property

```
var newItem = item.ToBsonDocument();
newItem.Add("IsDeleted", false);
```

Before I started to convert them to a document and just inserted the POCO class though the Mongo .NET driver it appeared to work.  Now that I am converting it,  any field that is left as the default or null are being saved that way.

Here is the convention that I have setup

```
var conventionPack = new ConventionPack { new IgnoreIfDefaultConvention(true) };
ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreIfDefault", conventionPack, x => true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appears to work for me... for example, after executing:

```
var item = new Item { Name = "John", Note = "abc" };
var newItem = item.ToBsonDocument();
newItem.Add("IsDeleted", false);
```

The value of newItem is:

```
"{ \"Name\" : \"John\", \"Note\" : \"abc\", \"IsDeleted\" : false }"
```

One thing you could check is to make sure you are registering your ConventionPack early enough. It has to be registered *before* the first attempt to serialize or deserialize an Item.